# autoscroll javascript function in chatbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, chat, autoscroll

how do i achieve a scroll down on my chatbox, because i cant see the realtime message. i want it to be called on my div id where my i put my style overflow

```
<script>
  //scroll to bottom
  window.onload=toBottom;
  function toBottom(){
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
  }//end of scroll to bottom
</script>
```

view part

```
<div class="scrollMessage w3-padding div" onload="toBottom" id="scroll" style="overflow-y:scroll;height: 460px;">
      <?php include 'getMessage.php'; ?>        
</div>
```

at first load it should already be on the last message

at actual chat conversation it will also be on the last message to show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you're looking for. Hope, it helps.

```js
var objDiv = document.getElementById("scroll2"); //Obtain the ID of the chat div
window.onload = toBottom;
function toBottom() {
  objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight; //Set the scroll offset position to the height of the chat div
}
```

```html
<div id="scroll">
<div class="scrollMessage w3-padding div" onload="toBottom" id="scroll2" style="overflow-y:scroll;height: 200px;width:150px;">
  <!--<?php include 'getMessage.php'; ?>-->
  Random messages <br>
  Random messages <br>
  Random messages <br>
  Random messages <br>
  Random messages <br>
  Random messages <br>
  Random messages <br>
  Random messages <br>
  Random messages <br>
  Random messages <br>
  Random messages <br>
  Random messages <br>
  Random messages <br>
  Random messages <br>
  Random messages <br>
  Random messages <br>
  Random messages <br>
  Random messages <br>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it did not work maybe because of my scrambled syntax:                                           
   `<div id="scroll">
        <div class="chatMessage w3-padding div" onload="toBottom" style="overflow-y:scroll;height: 460px;">
          <?php include 'getMessage.php'; ?>        
        </div>        
      </div>`

Comment: i tried to create a scroll id on top because chatMessage is linked to realtime function in js which is  `function getMessages() {
    $.get('<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/********/getMessage', function(data) {
      $(".chatMessage").html(data);
    });
  }
  setInterval(function() {
    getMessages()
  },500);`

Comment: @HanthonyTagam Then just create an id for the child div container and replace the name from scroll to that in the javascript as I just edited. Mark the answer up if it helped, cheers.

Comment: thanks for the answer man, i found out that it is because of my w3-modal which is the css framework that i used. maybe ill just find a pure css modal then. cheers,